# Problem installing matplotlib using conda and virtual environment. ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, environment

I have tried to install matplotlib in my environment "cs323V2"with the following commands:

```
(cs323V2) conda install matplotlib
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Retrieving notices: ...working... done
(cs323V2) python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[3]+  Stopped                 python
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: Are you sure that matplotlib was installed for the python version you're using? It looks like '(cs323V2) python' opens up python 2.7.5, which may not be the python version conda uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the conda-forge channel.

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

I am not really sure why only

```
conda install matplotlib
```

does not work.